# Wrapping method having argument with multiple types using package:js

Tags: javascript, dart, createjs, dart-js-interop

I am trying to wrap the following JavaScript library using `package:js`: [CreateJS](http://createjs.com)

The `EventDispatcher` "class" contains a method called `addEventListener` which I am having trouble wrapping. The method has the following signature:

```
addEventListener (type, listener, [useCapture])
```

where the parameters are:

- `type String`
- `listener Function | Object`
- `[useCapture] Boolean optional`

The source code for the method can be found here:
[addEventListener source code](http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/EventDispatcher.html#method_addEventListener)

How can I wrap this method when the `listener` parameter can be either `Function` or `Object`?

My current best attempt is:

```
@JS()
class EventDispatcher {
  external void addEventListener(String type, Object listener, [String bool useCapture]);
}
```

But how do I best make the method also accept `Function`?

Comment: When it's of type `Object`(like shown in your question) is doesn't accept `List` or `String`?

Comment: This might be a really bad example actually since List and String extends Object. I will update the question to use another CreateJS method which doesn't have this property.

Comment: I don't think that will gain more insight. AFAIK the only way is to have parameter types that common super classes (usually `dynamic` or `Object` if a more specific common super class is not available).